# How do I configure Spring Security to redirect to IDP after session timeout?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `SecurityConfiguration` class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that looks like so:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http
  .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
  .apply(SAMLConfigurer.saml())
      .serviceProvider()
            .keyStore()
            .storeFilePath(keystoreFilePath)
            .password(keystorePassword)
            .keyname(keystoreAlias)
            .keyPassword(keystorePassword)
            .and()
          .protocol(appProtocol)
          .hostname(appHostName)
          .basePath(appBasePath)
          .and()
      .identityProvider()
      .metadataFilePath(metadataFilePath);
}
```

The authentication works fine and dandy when first logging in, but after you are logged in for 7200 seconds (2 hours), you get an error. The exception is below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException: Authentication statement is too old to be used with value 2017-11-06T17:49:26.721Z
  at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAuthenticationStatement(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:538)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:306)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
  ... 75 more
```

This makes sense because the authentication from the IDP is from too long ago.

How do I configure Spring to redirect back to the IDP to get a new session when this happens?

Comment: hi nicholas79171, did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly a direct answer but helps solve the issue.

I had the same issue and when opening the source code of `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java` at line 538 it shows that validation is done against a default configuration of 7200 seconds.

From my experience ADFS and OKTA reuse authentications for more than 24h and even if you redirect back they will return the user with the same authentication causing and infinite redirect loop.

What I've done to solve this (may be incorrect/insecure) is to increase the value of `maxAuthenticationAge` by creating a `WebSSOProfileConsumer`  Bean and calling its `setMaxAuthenticationAge()`

```java
  /* set max authentication age in seconds - 3days * 24h * 3600sec/hour */
  private static final long MAX_AUTHENTICATION_AGE = 3 * 24 * 3600;
  ...
  @Bean
  public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
    WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl consumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    consumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(MAX_AUTHENTICATION_AGE);
    return consumer;
  }
```